# How can I import existing source into IntelliJ IDEA 12?

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm a newbie to IntelliJ IDEA.

I have a project built by grunt, the .iml, *.ipr, *.iws was added into the .gitignore, so when I clone the project from git, there is no .iml file. How can I add it into IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: Is there a pom.xml? Can you just import that to intellij??

Comment: You really need to be using maven. Everything else sucks.

Comment: Thanks for the response, actually there is no pom.xml there, i finally use create new web project based on existing source and it works ok for me:)